# How to get the process when I use ssh to a remote server to git a repository?

Tags: linux, shell

I am from China, and for some reason git connect is very slow. I know how to use git proxy, but still not fast.

What I know and tried is to SSH to my VPS and download git repository in my VPS. and then I zip the repository fold and SCP the zip from in my local computer. In this way, finally I get my git repository which it very comfortable for my and it is fast!!!

Now I want to know, is there a simple command or shell to achieve this?
I cant handle it by typing every time but it is not effective.

Answer (score 1):

`scp` relies on `ssh`. You can always clone the repository over `ssh` from your VPS. In one line you could do something like this:

```
$ ssh <VPS> git clone https://<project.git> && git clone ssh://VPS/<project.git>
```

[Reference](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols)